How to solve 'configFactory is not a function'?
I'm working on node.js and I tried npm start, then I got configFactory is not a function. Does anyone know how to fix it??
I already tried 'npm cache clean --force' and 'npm install' again, but it didn't work...
I also tried updating node.

"configFactory" is something that is specific to your project. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
